# Best way to load GCP AssetInventory into BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bigtable

Asset inventories are exported to Cloud Storage in JSON.  I want to load this data into BigTable, but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

I'm thinking the pipeline will look something like Cloud Storage > ETL to CSV/sequence files > Load into BigTable using DataFlow.

What are the options for loading JSON Cloud Storage data into BigTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both JSON and Bigtable are so flexible and amorphous, there are no pre-packaged conversions between the two. Google provides all of the pieces, but you  have to write some code to glue them together. Specifically mapping the JSON documents to Bigtable's columns and rows has to be done from scratch.

- Use a Cloud Asset client [1] to export the assets to GCS.
- Depending on the size of the exports, either

  - create a dataflow job that uses TextIO to read the export
  - or use a Cloud Storage Client [2] directly
- Use your favorite JSON library to parse each line
- Transform the each JSON object into a Bigtable mutation
- Use either a Dataflow BigtableIO[3] sink or a Bigtable client [4] to write the data to Bigtable

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/libraries
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries
[3] https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.html
[4] https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries